# How large does a graph need to be to trigger the worst-case complexity of a Fibonacci heap?

Tags: java, data-structures, dijkstra, fibonacci

I've been trying to trigger the worst-case complexity of a Fibonacci heap by using it with Dijkstra's algorithm but apparently with no luck. I have a second implementation of Dijkstra's using a vanilla binary heap, and it ALWAYS seems to win. I was told to conduct my tests using larger datasets, which I have, as shown (copy-pasted straight from my program):

```
Running Dijkstra's algorithm with 3354 nodes and 8870 links...
Source node: ALL
Time using binary heap = 2167698339 ns (2167.70 ms)
```

versus...

```
Running Dijkstra's algorithm with 3354 nodes and 8870 links...
Source node: ALL
Time using Fibonacci heap = 11863138070 ns (11863.14 ms)
```

2 seconds, against ~12 seconds. Quite a difference alright.

Now, I have another graph with a whopping 264,000 nodes and 733,000 edges. I haven't had the chance to test it yet, but would that be enough for the theoretical advantage of Fibonacci heaps to shine?

I hope I don't need something with over a million nodes. I mean it's not the biggest issue in the world but it would be nice to see the difference in action for once.

Comment: Which worst case are you looking for? The asymptotic bounds for Dijkstra with Fibonacci heaps are strictly better than for the version with binary heaps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. I'm not sure if it would be possible to show that with a large enough graph, though. I've been trying different datasets of different sizes to see if the F-heap will perform better for once. No luck so far; the binary heap always wins.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. Well, you'll probably need a very large graph. In my experience, binary heaps are very hard to beat, and skew heaps are the backup for when they don't work, while Fibonacci heaps are mostly nice when you're doing CS theory.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question's title is not correct. Size of input does not affect the worst case complexity. What you need is the size of the graph where the asymptotic computational complexity of the Fibonacci heap makes up for its constant factor. Remember the good old `O(n)`? Well `O(n)` would mean that for large enough datasets your algorithm will perform approximately `k*n` operations, where k is a fixed number. This `k` is the constant I am refering to. Now if you have an algorithm with complexity `O(n)` and another with compexity `O(n*log(n))`, this still does not mean that the first one is always faster than the second one. Imagine first one performs k<sub>1</sub>*n operations and the second one performs k<sub>2</sub>n*log(n) operations. Now if k<sub>1</sub> = k<sub>2</sub> * 1000, than the fact that the first algortihm will be faster than the second one only if n > 21000, which is **quite large**. What is important is that if you have a value for which the first algorithm will overtake the second one.

Depending on the implementation of a given datastructure, the constant may vary and thus you may need several times larger dataset to make up for it. I have seen some results where fibonacci heap got faster than plain old binary heap at about 500 000 edges(and about 5000 nodes) but these are only for that particular implementation. In your implemenation the difference may show earlier, or later depending on how efficiently you implemented both structures. What is certain is that if you implemented the data structures with correct complexities, the difference will show for some n(but it may happen that no existing computer can handle graphs that big).

Answer (score 0):

I think your fibonacci heap is not necessarily faster for large graphs. What you need to increase is the number of decreaseKey operations. You should get more such operations if the mean degree of the nodes increases (so a high dimensional graph). Or one could say if the graph gets more complete (highly interconnected).